# Automate an equation form previous code

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfmath

I am using the following code to display a number line, but I have had to write in the equation for each line, can you help me to make this equation automated?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\addsubnumlinetoright}[3]{%

\begin{tikzpicture}[out=45,in=135,relative,>=stealth]
\draw[<->] (#1-2,0)--(#2+2,0);
\foreach \x in {\number\numexpr#1-1\relax,...,\number\numexpr#2+1\relax}  
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below]      {\footnotesize $\x$};
\fill (#1,0) circle (2pt);
\fill (#2,0) circle (2pt);

\pgfmathsetmacro{\End}{#2-1} 
\draw[#3,shorten >=2pt]
\foreach \i in {#1,...,\End}{%
     (\i,0) to (\i+1,0)
} ; 
 \node[color=OrangeRed] at (#2,-0.75) {\small End};
 \node[color=Cerulean] at (#1,-0.75) {\small Start};
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xtxt}{(#1+#2)/2}
 \node at (\xtxt,1) {$-5 +8 = 3$};  %code I would like to change
 \node at (\xtxt,0.5) {\small Move \number\numexpr#2-#1\relax\ units to the      \emph{right}};
 \end{tikzpicture}}

 \newcommand{\addsubnumlinetoleft}[3]{%

\begin{tikzpicture}[out=135,in=45,>=stealth]
\draw[<->] (#2-2,0)--(#1+2,0);
\foreach \x in {\number\numexpr#2-1\relax,...,\number\numexpr#1+1\relax}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below]  {\footnotesize $\x$};
\fill (#1,0) circle (2pt);
\fill (#2,0) circle (2pt);

\pgfmathsetmacro{\End}{#2+1} 
 \draw[#3,shorten >=2pt]
 \foreach \i in {#1,...,\End}{%
    (\i,0) to  (\i-1,0)
} ; 
\node[color=OrangeRed] at (#2,-0.75) {\small End };
\node[color=Cerulean] at (#1,-0.75) {\small Start };
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xtxt}{(#1+#2)/2}     
  \node at (\xtxt,1) {$2 - 6=  -4$}; % Code I would like to change
 \node at (\xtxt,0.5) {\small Move \number\numexpr-#2+#1\relax\ units to the      \emph{left}};
\end{tikzpicture}} 


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\addsubnumlinetoright{3}{7}{->,color=MidnightBlue}

\addsubnumlinetoright{-5}{-3}{->,color=MidnightBlue}

\addsubnumlinetoright{-5}{3}{->,color=MidnightBlue}

\addsubnumlinetoleft{2}{-4}{->,color=MidnightBlue}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The lines of code I have indicated are L21 and L42. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `\addsubnumlinetoright` (sign tex-sx doesn't support `diff` highlighting),

```tex
% before
  \node at (\xtxt,1) {$-5 +8 = 3$};  %code I would like to change
% after
  \node at (\xtxt,1) {$#1 + \the\numexpr#2-(#1)\relax = #2$};
```

In `\addsubnumlinetoleft`:

```tex
% before
  \node at (\xtxt,1) {$2 - 6=  -4$}; % Code I would like to change
% after
  \node at (\xtxt,1) {$#1 - \the\numexpr#1-(#2)\relax = #2$};
```

Full example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\addsubnumlinetoright}[3]{%

\begin{tikzpicture}[out=45,in=135,relative,>=stealth]
\draw[<->] (#1-2,0)--(#2+2,0);
\foreach \x in {\number\numexpr#1-1\relax,...,\number\numexpr#2+1\relax}  
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below]      {\footnotesize $\x$};
\fill (#1,0) circle (2pt);
\fill (#2,0) circle (2pt);

\pgfmathsetmacro{\End}{#2-1} 
\draw[#3,shorten >=2pt]
\foreach \i in {#1,...,\End}{%
     (\i,0) to (\i+1,0)
} ; 
 \node[color=OrangeRed] at (#2,-0.75) {\small End};
 \node[color=Cerulean] at (#1,-0.75) {\small Start};
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xtxt}{(#1+#2)/2}
 \node at (\xtxt,1) {$#1 + \the\numexpr#2-(#1)\relax = #2$};  %code I would like to change
 \node at (\xtxt,0.5) {\small Move \number\numexpr#2-#1\relax\ units to the      \emph{right}};
 \end{tikzpicture}}

 \newcommand{\addsubnumlinetoleft}[3]{%

\begin{tikzpicture}[out=135,in=45,>=stealth]
\draw[<->] (#2-2,0)--(#1+2,0);
\foreach \x in {\number\numexpr#2-1\relax,...,\number\numexpr#1+1\relax}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below]  {\footnotesize $\x$};
\fill (#1,0) circle (2pt);
\fill (#2,0) circle (2pt);

\pgfmathsetmacro{\End}{#2+1} 
 \draw[#3,shorten >=2pt]
 \foreach \i in {#1,...,\End}{%
    (\i,0) to  (\i-1,0)
} ; 
\node[color=OrangeRed] at (#2,-0.75) {\small End };
\node[color=Cerulean] at (#1,-0.75) {\small Start };
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xtxt}{(#1+#2)/2}     
  \node at (\xtxt,1) {$#1 - \the\numexpr#1-(#2)\relax = #2$}; % Code I would like to change
 \node at (\xtxt,0.5) {\small Move \number\numexpr-#2+#1\relax\ units to the      \emph{left}};
\end{tikzpicture}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\addsubnumlinetoright{3}{7}{->,color=MidnightBlue}

\addsubnumlinetoright{-5}{-3}{->,color=MidnightBlue}

\addsubnumlinetoright{-5}{3}{->,color=MidnightBlue}

\addsubnumlinetoleft{2}{-4}{->,color=MidnightBlue}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, and more thanks for the explanation!